# How to make Notepad++ open file browser in current folder?

Tags: notepad++

I set Notepad++ to be called from command-line. I would like it to open file browser in current folder from which it was called so that I could work with files in that folder. Is there any way to do this; any suggestions, ideas how to go about it? Textmate has this feature, which is very convenient.

[edit]
To clarify, I was looking to get this from explorer plugin that open on the side. I don't see any option in the config. Maybe it can't be done, I was hoping someone might know more.
[/edit]

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: I thought it already does this? I opened cmd, navigated to Desktop, ran "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", and the defaulted folder was 'Desktop'. I've changed the current commandprompt dir and then called notepad++ again, and it changes with the directory change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked my installation of Notepad++. When I invoke it via the command-line I am able to have it open the current folder for file saves/opens. How are you invoking Notepad++ from the command-line? What I have done is, append *C:\Program Files\Notepad++* to the PATH variable.

Comment: I meant the explorer window on the side that you can have open, it is bundled with notepad++ as a dll, if this works for you, then I get something messed up here, which is great because it would mean it works

Answer (score 3):

I was just facing the same problem and was unsatisfied with the solution above. From [here](http://leesongj.com/?p=8):

> - First, open the run dialog  (Run menu or F5).
> - Type “`explorer $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)`”.
> - Click Save.. to map this with your fav accelerator key – and that’s it.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to have the explorer plugin follow current dir. But this option does not seem to be available. I think the closest you can get is through a combination of key shortcut. What I suggest is:

***Initial Configuration***

1. Map the "Current Dir. Path to Clipboard" to a combination of your choice say: *Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar*
2. Do a similar binding for the Explorer plugin command "Go to Path...":  *Ctrl+Shift+P*

***Usage scenario:***

1. Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar
2. Ctrl+Shift+P
3. Paste (using ubiquitous Ctrl-V)
4. Enter.

This can be done fairly fast, when you need it.

Hope this helps.